# ASP.NET deployment web service - could not load type namespace.application

Tags: asp.net, web-services, deployment

After building the web service and publishing dll files under the bin folder and web.config file under the main directory to my hosting but it shows the following error:

[image]

cs:

```
namespace jsonwebservice
{
    public class getvideos:IHttpHandler
    {
        ...
```

web.config:

```
﻿<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <directoryBrowse enabled="false" />
        <defaultDocument>
            <files>
                <clear/>
                <add value="Default.htm" />
                <add value="Default.asp" />
                <add value="index.htm" />
                <add value="index.html" />
                <add value="iisstart.htm" />
                <add value="default.aspx" />
                <add value="index.php" />
            </files>
        </defaultDocument>
        <httpErrors errorMode="DetailedLocalOnly" existingResponse="Auto" />
        <handlers>
        <add name="getdata" path="getdata" verb="*" type="jsonwebservice.getvideos" resourceType="Unspecified" preCondition="integratedMode" />
        </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```